# Simple WebClient works locally, but not when deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, webclient

I have a very simple test app that creates a WebClient and gets a response from a third-party API (sensitive info removed):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    var baseAddress = new Uri("https://test-url");

    client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";            

    var parms = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(
        "{ \"username\":\"<USERNAME>\"," +
           "\"password\":\<PASSWORD>\"," +
           "\"client_id\":\"<CLIENT_ID>\"," +
           "\"client_secret\":\"<CLIENT_SECRET>\"" +
        "}"
    );

    // Get access token
    var responseObject = new ResponseObject();
    var responseBytes = new byte[] { };
    string responseBody;           

    try
    {
        responseBytes = client.UploadData(baseAddress, "POST", parms);
        responseBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject>(responseBody);
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        var resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusDescription);
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly when I run it locally, multiple times. I get a response back and I'm able to extract the information I need from it.

However, once I deploy this code to Azure, I try to call the API with POSTMAN and I get an error telling me that there's an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error on this line in the try/catch:

```
var resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
```

[image: Indication of error-causing line]

So, I attached a remote debugger to the API and stepped through this small bit of code. What's weird to me is that I can see right when the program jumps into the `catch` portion of the code, but there is no `ex` Exception object. What I mean by that is that I can hover over the `ex` variable in debug and nothing appears. Even hovering over `ex.Response` shows nothing. So, since there is nothing there (i.e. `ex` doesn't appear to exist, not even a `null` value) the application bombs with the null reference error.

My thought is that maybe something in Azure is blocking the URL, since I can run this locally without issue. I asked our network guys here about it and they said there shouldn't be any kind of constraints set up that they are aware of to prevent the call from going out. The weird thing is that I turned on diagnostic logging in Azure for this app and nothing is showing up. Even though I can hit the app with a browser or PostMan, nothing is appearing in the log. So, that's another weird thing. I'd expect to be able to see *something*.

Anyway, I'm hoping that perhaps someone has ran into something like this before and can point me to an article/solution/blog that may shed light on this and get me to a working solution.

Thanks!

EDIT: Added a screenshot of the error message as it appears in the browser:

[image]

EDIT: Added the line on which the app is throwing the exception below:

```
responseBytes = client.UploadData(baseAddress, "POST", parms);
```

Immediately after trying to execute this line, it jumps to the `catch`, but there is no WebException, it appears.

EDIT: I've found the solution and added it as an answer below.

Comment: Do you have any network logs to determine whether traffic is actually getting out? Also are there any NSG's configured on the server's network group on Azure?

Comment: Which line in the `try` block is throwing?

Comment: @ColinM I'll ask our network guys if they can provide me this information. I'm not seeing anything in the app logs in Azure.

Comment: @mxmissile I've edited my question above to include the line that's throwing the exception.

Comment: Have you tried adding `catch (Exception ex)` and logging the `ex` object for trace purposes? I'd also recommend using `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`, though that may possibly not matter too much here in this case.

Comment: @ColinM I'm adding the Exception ex now and deploying it to Azure as we "speak".

Comment: @ColinM Also, weirdly enough, I tried using HttpClient before this, but kept getting a 415 error from the server (when I ran it locally) because it kept saying the Content-Type was not supported, even though I had it explicitly set to 'application/json' as I was instructed by their (3rd party) docs to do. So, when I switched to WebClient, it worked fine and I was able to get authenticated and get data back from the 3rd-party API. But, once in Azure it was a no-go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that worked and it took one line of code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

So, basically, I just had to set the SecurityProtocol. I don't know how this was working locally without it, but running it on Azure requires it to be set, apparently.

Comment: It's possible that TLS1.2 hasn't been set as the default on the Azure VM and that it's using TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 when making the HTTPS call. Ensure your project is targeting NET 4.6.2 or greater, and if httpRuntime is specified in the web.config also ensure that target framework is 4.6.2

Comment: @ColinM Thanks for the advice! I'll check those settings now.